# why i'm getting Run time exception while cloning an object in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to perform shallow cloning of an object My dog class has a primitive variable i=10 and also a reference variable point to an object  j=20 and also I define a clone method as public however I'm getting a runtime error saying Exception in thread "main" java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException

```
package com.objectclasscoding.practice;

import com.objectclasscoding.practice.Cat.Dog;

class Cat {
    int j;

    public Cat(int j) {

        this.j = j;
    }

    class Dog implements Cloneable {
        Cat c;
        int i;

        public Dog(Cat c, int i) {
            this.c = c;
            this.i = i;
        }

    }

    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return (Dog) super.clone();
    }
}

public class ShallowCloningDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        Cat c = new Cat(20);
        Dog d1 = c.new Dog(c, 10);
        System.out.println(d1.i + ".." + c.j);

        Dog d2 = (Dog) d1.c.clone();
        d1.i = 888;
        d1.c.j = 999;
        System.out.println(d2.i + ".." + d2.c.j);

    }

}
```

After running this code I'm getting runtime error saying `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException`

Comment: Why is `Dog` an inner-class of `Cat`?

Comment: A dog is the main object in which c is just a reference variable pointing to an object whose value j=20 is just an example to check if clone dog object that whether it is shallow cloning or deep cloning

Comment: Then `Dog` should be a top-level class, not an inner-class of `Cat`. And right now, you are trying to clone `Cat`, not `Dog`.

Comment: Now figure out my code mistake thank you @MarkRotteveel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be calling clone on `d1.c`, an instance of `Cat`, which does not implement `Cloneable`.

For some reason you've added a `clone()` method to `Cat` rather than `Dog`. Inside that method, you tried to cast the result to `Dog`, as if a cloned `Cat` would be an instance of `Dog`. That does not make sense. Cats are notoriously not the same as dogs.

Comment: yes exactly I should call **clone()** to dog instance rather than cat but if I'm calling clone() to dog then in my eclipse I'm getting an error saying **the method clone() from the type object is not visible**  'public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
  Cat c = new Cat(20);
  Dog d1 =new Dog(c, 10);
  System.out.println(d1.i + ".." + c.j);

  Dog d2 = (Dog)d1.clone(); **Here on clone I'm getting that error**
  d1.i = 888;
  d1.c.j = 999;
  System.out.println(d2.i + ".." + d2.c.j);
 }'  @khelwood

Comment: You didn't write a clone method on `Dog`, so you can't call it. You wrote a clone method on `Cat` and then you called that.